# New WS install win11 Pro and O365: Connection to DB fails due to change in ownership from SQL to Azure. Is it a Permissions issue?

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure, windows-11

Security System: Unable to connect to Local Database Template[image].

Error Message: The remote computer that you are trying to connect to requires Network Level Authentication (NLA), but your Windows domain controller cannot be contacted to perform NLA.